# Laravel hasMany detach

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am having an issue with Eloquent regarding removing child model:
When this is executed in `process2()` I still have the deleted model which is not ok.

### Model

```
    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Model1 extends Model
    {
        public function seasons() {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Seasons', 'series_id', 'id');
        }
    }
```

### Service

```
class Process {
    public function process1($model1Instance) {

        for($model1Instance->seasons() as $season) {
            if(//whatever//) {
                $season->delete();
            }
        }
    }
    public function process2($model1Instance) {
        for($model1Instance->seasons() as $season) {
            //At this point I still have the deleted instance
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
$proc = new Process();
......
$proc->process1($model1Instance);
$proc->process2($model1Instance);
```

When `process1()` removes a model from the parent, how can I have it removed in `process2()`?

### Tried/Will try:

1.Method:
    $model1Instance->seasons()->detach($season);
but got: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::detach()`

2.Another class
    I could make another simple class to store these but I do not think it is okay, although I could then set filtered seasons but still have to use Model1 instance:

```
class Model1Copy {
    private $seasons;
    public function __construct($seasons) {
        $this->seasons = $seasons;
    }
}
```

3. Fatal when tried:

   public function process1($model1Instance) {

   ```
   for($model1Instance->seasons() as $season) {
       if(//whatever//) {
           $season->delete();
       } else {
       $childs[]=$season;
       }
   }
   $model1Instance->seasons = $childs
   ```

   }
4. Would be to make my own repositories to skip the ORM`s behavior, but it is frustrating because I have to rewrite all queries just to remove an instance...

Comment: I guess the `$season->delete()` call is failing because there's a mapping for that Season to Model1. First detach it and then delete it.

Comment: The delete method works ok, but is still available in the parent model and ends up in process2()

Comment: It Works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323458/can-detach-method-also-be-applied-to-one-to-many-relationship-in-laravel

Answer (score 7):

To delete `hasMany` records with condition:

```
$model1Instance->seasons()->where('condition', 'met')->delete();
```

To delete all:

```
$model1Instance->seasons()->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$model->seasons()` returns the relation, whereas `$model->seasons` returns the Collection of Season mapped to the model. Try the following.

```
public function process1($model1Instance) {

    // Iterate over the collection
    for($model1Instance->seasons as $season) {
        if(condition) {
            $model1Instance->seasons()->detach($season); 
            $season->delete();
        }
    }

    $model1Instance->save();
}
```

Also, you're iterating all seasons of all models, and deleting seasons that satisfy some condition. Wouldn't it be more efficient if you destroy all seasons in one go. Something like the following:

```
$seasons = Season::where(condition)->get();
Season::destroy($seasons);
```

Comment: Seemed reasonable but got: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sync()

Comment: Updated. Use `$model1Instance->season`.

Comment: Unfortunately I still have an exception: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::sync()

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `$model1Instance->seasons()->sync($childs)` and not `$model1Instance->seasons->sync($childs)`?

Comment: Sadly yes:
$series->seasons()->sync($seasons);
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sync() 

$series->seasons->sync($seasons);
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::sync()

Comment: Saw in the doc:

You may also use the sync method to construct many-to-many associations

Comment: If it helps I am running process1() and process2() in a foreach: $models = Model1::all();

Comment: You're right. `sync` is only for many to many relations. Also, from the docs, you need to save the model once you're done. See updated answer.

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::detach(), I think I will add the check from process1 into process2 to skip this, Thank you verry much for your time!

Comment: I am removing old seasons then adding new ones so I can`t use destroy unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function process1($model1Instance) {

    // Iterate over the collection
    for($model1Instance->seasons as $season) {
        if(condition) {
            $season->delete();
        }
    }

    $model1Instance->save();
}
```