# can detach() method also be applied to one to many relationship in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

in Laravel documentation i found detach() method to detach all objects in many to many relationships. Can detach() method also be applied to one to many relationship in Laravel? if not, how can I detach all n objects in this case?

Comment: detach() method in laravel is not used for deleting objects. It will just detach the relation between two models

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In many to many relationships, detach() method only delete pivot entry in your database, except if you have specific cascade deleting.

For one to many relationship, you want to use dissociate() method to unbind the relation and associate() to bind it on the belongsTo Side.

```
    $comment->post()->associate($post->id);
```

On the contrary, you would add account using attach() on the hasMany side:

```
    $post->comments()->attach($comment->id);
```

To delete all comments you would do :

```
    $post->comments()->delete();
```

More info here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Beware that calling `delete()` on a `HasMany` relationship will not disassociate the related models, but delete them from the database completely! If you only need to remove the relationship, this is NOT the way to go. In fact it looks like Laravel has no built in method for that, so you need to iterate over all children and disassociate them one-by-one. Alternatively a direct db query can do it in one go. A solution can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61135296/1319004

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships)

> When removing a belongsTo relationship, you may use the dissociate
>   method. This method will set the relationship's foreign key to null

```
$user->account()->dissociate();

$user->save();
```