# How to dissociate elements from a HasMany relation?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

There's the `save` and `saveMany` methods on the `HasMany` relation class, but where are the `dissociate(Many)`/`detach(Many)` methods? There's also no built-in way to get the inverse relationship method, so what's the best way to dissociate an array of id's/models from a `HasMany` relationship object.

Currently I'm using:

```
$hasMany = $parent->theRelationship(); // Get the relationship object.
$child = $hasMany->getRelated(); // Get an empty related model.
$key = $hasMany->getForeignKeyName(); // Get the name of the column on the child to set to NULL.
$child->findMany($IDs)->each(function($model) use ($key) {
  $model->$key = NULL;
  $model->save();
});
```

This could be alot shorter with something like:

```
$hasMany = $parent->theRelationship();
$hasMany->dissociate($IDs);
```

Bonus points if you have any official answers from Taylor as to why he hasn't implemented this, I've seen him close feature requests of this kind on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why there isn't a function, but to be more performant than your example, you could use the DB class like:

```
\DB::table('child_table')->where('parent_id', $parent->id)->update(['parent_id' => null]);
```

Comment: Ok, this replaces the `findMany` statement with something more efficient right? To retrieve the name of the column `parent_id` and the name of the child table I'd still have to go through the rest of my snippet.

Comment: Note that OP wanted to work with a specific set of child resources instead of all, also he does not know the foreign table and column name in advance, so this would be more appropriate:
`$key = $parent->theRelationship()->getForeignKeyName(); \DB::table($parent->theRelationship()->getModel()->getTable())->where($key, $parent->id)->whereIn('id', $IDs)->update([$key => null]);`

Answer (score 0):

The performatic way (1 db update):

```
$partent->theRelationship()->update(['parent_id' => null]);
```

The readable way (multiple db updates):

```
$parent->theRelationship->each->parentRelationship()->dissociate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'ts a old question but i came acrros with this macro:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

HasMany::macro('dissociate', function() {
    $foreignKey = $this->getForeignKeyName();
    $this->each(function($relation) use ($foreignKey) {
        $relation->update([$foreignKey => null]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use detach like so;

```
$parent->theRelationship()->detach([1,2,3])
```

Where you pass an array of IDs.

From Laravel documentation:
"For convenience, attach and detach also accept arrays of IDs as input"

Comment: Isn't this only for `BelongsToMany` relationship? detach does not exist on HasMany, or does it? I don't see it in the API reference

Comment: Right, the `detach()` method only available for `BelongsToMany`. It is part of `InteractsWithPivotTable`, which as the name suggests is not used with simple foreign key relationships.