# Laravel hasMany relationship detach all

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

Is there a simple solution to detach (without deleting) all related models through a hasMany Relation on a model?

For example, I have two tables:

- College (id, name)
- Student (id, name, college_id(nullable) )

In the College model I define this relationship:

```
class College extends Model
{
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Student','college_id','id');
    }
}
```

What is the best way to detach all current College students from the College (i.e, get all the students of the college and set their college_id to `null`)?

Is there an easy way to detach all students from the College model using eloquent?

Something like

```
class College extends Model
{
    ...
    public function detachAllStudents()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

P.S. already have read this question [Laravel hasMany detach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662569/laravel-hasmany-detach), but get errors when I try to apply it to my application

Comment: detach for many to many i think you need to use dissociate()

Comment: No, dissociate() only works for hasOne relationships.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can detach all the college students as below. Actually, we already have the `college_id` in your `students` table and we have to make this `college_id` null somehow. This is not called detach in Eloquent. The word `detach` come when you have `many to many` relationships. So, let's just update the students and see if it works or not.

```
$college->students()->update(['college_id' => null);
```

So, you method can be completed as below:

```
public function detachAllStudents()
{
    $college->students()->update(['college_id' => null]);
}
```

That's it!

Comment: Thanks for answer, but calling $this->students()->detach(); in Model class causes "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::detach()"

Comment: Sorry, you told detach so, I thought it's many to many relationship. Actually you have one to many relationship. In that case we have to go with `update()` method instead. I have updated the answer. Please check and see if it works.

Comment: Yes it is right answer, finally got smart one line solution, thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships:

**Toggling Associations**

The many-to-many relationship also provides a toggle method which "toggles" the attachment status of the given IDs. If the given ID is currently attached, it will be detached. Likewise, if it is currently detached, it will be attached:

```
$user->roles()->toggle([1, 2, 3]);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but calling $this->students()->toggle([1]);; in Model class causes "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::toggle()

Comment: I thought you had a Many to Many relationship because you used the word detach. Saw that Imran succesfuly answered you question catching that difference in terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Despite Imran answer perfectly fits this scenario I would add a more generic approach. Let's say `$college` respects an interface instead of an implementation, you wouldn't know the foreign key at run time.

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

interface HasStudents {
    public function students(): HasMany;
}

class College extends Model implements HasStudents
{
    public function students(): HasMany;
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class, 'college_id', 'id');
    }
}

function detachStudents(HasStudents $model): void {
    $studentsRelationship = $model->students();
    $studentsRelationship->update([
        $studentsRelationship->getQualifiedForeignKeyName() => null
    ]);
}

detachStudents($college);
```